# Appending two strings to one index in an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, append

I've fixed it exactly how I want it now. If anyone else has the same issue I think this is the easiest and most efficient way of trying to set up a deck of cards. You can pick out individual cards using a random variable in deck[random][0] and deck[random][1].
Thanks for all the help, here is my code:

```
public class NewDeck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] suits = new String[] { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts" };

        String[] faces = new String[] { "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack" };

        String[][] deck = new String[suits.length * (faces.length + 9)][2];

        int a = 0;

        for (String y : suits) {

            for (String x : faces) {

                deck[a][0] = x;
                deck[a][1] = y;
                a++;

            }

        }

        for (String y : suits) {

            for (int p = 2; p < 11; p++) {

                deck[a][1] = y;
                String pp = Integer.toString(p);
                deck[a][0] = pp;
                a++;

            }

        }

        for (int p = 0; p < deck.length; p++) {

            System.out.print(deck[p][0] + " of ");
            System.out.println(deck[p][1]);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: it will give you a compilaton error - `deck.add(suits[suit], faces[face]); ` , deck is not a map instance.

Comment: Why don't you create a Class **Card** which has two properties "Suit" and "Face"? This is what Java is all about!

Comment: @ tech-idiot: I get the error on my for loop saying: 'length cannot be resolved or is not a field'
And an error on - deck.add(suits[suit], faces[face]); - saying 'The type of expression must be an Array but is resolved to a list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add parameter types to your strings and create a `Pair` class. Note that you will need a Java compiler of version 1.5 or higher for the generics.

```
class Pair {

     private final String face;  
     private final String suit;  

     Pair(String suit, String face) {
         this.face = face; 
         this.suit = suit;             
     }
     @Override
     public String toString() {
        return "(" + suit + ", " + face + ")";
     }
}
```

Then you can use this `Pair` class as follows, using the appropriate `List` methods `get` and `size`:

```
List<Pair> deck = new ArrayList<Pair>();

List<String> suits = new ArrayList<String>();
suits.add("Hearts");
suits.add("Diamonds");
suits.add("Clubs");
suits.add("Spades");

List<String> faces = new ArrayList<String>();
faces.add("Ace");
faces.add("King");
faces.add("Queen");
faces.add("Jack");

for(int suit = 0; suit < suits.size(); suit++){

    for(int face = 0; face < faces.size(); face++){

        deck.add(new Pair(suits.get(suit), faces.get(face)));             

    }

}
```

If you override the `toString` method of `Pair` you can also `System.out.println(deck)` to get your desired string representation of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! But I'm afraid I don't understand all your code fully, so I think I may need to learn a bit more java before moving onto making games that I'm not capable of doing at the moment. But with what you've given me, I might be able to carry on making the game, I think I can only learn by trying things I haven't done before. Thanks a million.

Comment: Since generics were introduced only in java 1.5 there are still many tutorials and books for Java Collections out there which are out of date. I think an okay place to start may be here (short and contains furhter links) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java. Perhaps find a good up-to-date Java book?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change this

```
        deck.add(suits[suit], faces[face]);
```

with

```
        deck.add(suits[suit] + faces[face]);
```

as your idea  is to concatenate elements from the list and add it the deck list.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store two values at one index of List. But what you can do is

**Option 1**
Store concatenated \string like

Change

```
   deck.add(suits[suit], faces[face]);
```

with

```
   deck.add(suits[suit] + "," + faces[face]);
```

then output deck[2] = suit, face

**Option 2**
Change  list of string to list of Object and this object contains detail of suit and face

```
public class Deck {
    private String suit;
    private String face;

// getter and setters;
}
```

and list become

```
List<Deck> deck
```

and add entry as

```
deck.add(new Deck(suits[suit], faces[face]))
```